# Сортировка в C#

Tags: c#, сортировка, unity3d

Пишу игру на Unity.

Имею список персонажей, которые имеют различные атаки с разной скоростью. Например: Рубящий удар - скорость 3, колющий удар - скорость 5 и т.д. Чем больше число, тем быстрее.

Я раздаю своим персонажам команды (всего около 10 персонажей). После того как все персонажи получили свои команды, они поочередно должны атаковать противника. У противника точно такой же механизм.

Все свои команды/атаки я добавляю в один лист (атака хранит в себе скорость, повреждения, кто атакует, кого атакуют).

Далее должна произойти сортировка листа по скорости атаки так, чтобы самые быстрые оказались в начале листа, с условием: если в очереди есть две атаки с одинаковой скоростью, то каждый раз при новой сортировке первоначального листа очередность между ними выбиралась случайно.

Например, добавил в лист: рубящий удар №1, колющий удар №1, колющий удар №2.
И после сортировки получил: колющий удар №1, колющий удар №2, рубящий удар №1.
А в другой раз при сортировке получил: колющий удар №2, колющий удар №1, рубящий удар №1.

Долго бьюсь и никак не могу решить эту задачу. 
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать LINQ. Сначала с помощью OrderBy() отсортировать по скорости. Затем с помощью ThenBy() отсортировать по случайному числу.

Вот небольшой пример:

```
class AttackInfo
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }

    public AttackInfo(string description, int speed)
    {
        Description = description;
        Speed = speed;
    }
}

var rnd = new Random();

List<AttackInfo> attacks = new List<AttackInfo>();
attacks.Add(new AttackInfo("Колющая 1", 5));
attacks.Add(new AttackInfo("Колющая 2", 5));
attacks.Add(new AttackInfo("Рубящая 1", 3));

IOrderedEnumerable<AttackInfo> sortedAttacks = attacks.OrderByDescending(n => n.Speed).ThenBy(n => rnd.Next(0, 101));

do
{
    foreach (var a in sortedAttacks)
    {
        Console.Write(a.Description);
        Console.Write(", ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar);
```

Comment: Спасибо больше! С LINQ ознакомлюсь, думаю для данной задачи хватит.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к C#, тут просто нужно придумать алгоритм и реализовать его. Например, введите вашим персонажам ещё один параметр: случайное число. Перед каждой сортировкой каждый персонаж должен обновить это случайное число. Затем в процессе сортировки если скорость атаки двух персонажей равна, первым идёт тот персонаж, чьё случайное число больше (или меньше - как вам удобнее).